# Why laravel query doesn't return right result?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have this code in laravel to get the products that will run out soon.

```
$productos = DB::table('productos')
                  ->where('producto_minimo', '>=', 'producto_cantidad')
                  ->get();
```

And what I get is the following result
[image: Laravel Result]

which is not the right result. While in MySql I get the right results whith this query `SELECT * FROM productos where producto_minimo >= producto_cantidad;` 
[image: MySql Result]

**Update**

The query log - `DB::getQueryLog()` -  shows this

```
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'query' => string 'select * from `productos` where `producto_minimo` >= ?' (length=54)
      'bindings' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'producto_cantidad' (length=17)
      'time' => float 1
```

Comment: I'd truly think _actually_ posting the result instead of  posting a picture will be easier on all of us.

Comment: I did, but I couldn't publish the question "too much code"

Comment: Have you tried enabling debug=true in database.php so that you can log the actual database queries that are executed?

Comment: @giannischristofakis the `id 4` should be the only result, but I get all the rows in the table.

Comment: Yeah, first result is way wrong: producto_minimo = 10 which is < than producto_cantidad = 20...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you've got to use the `whereRaw` method:

```
$productos = DB::table('productos')
                  ->whereRaw('producto_minimo >= producto_cantidad')
                  ->get();
```

Your query will compare the value in the column `producto_minimo` with the string 'producto_cantidad'

Have a look at Eloquents documentation of [advanced wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres):

```
DB::table('users')
        ->whereExists(function($query)
        {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                  ->from('orders')
                  ->whereRaw('orders.user_id = users.id');
        })
        ->get();
```

> The query above will produce the following SQL:

```
select * from users
where exists (
    select 1 from orders where orders.user_id = users.id
)
```